# How to add a row on top of the table and below <th>?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

> How to add a row on top of the table and below (<-th->) ?

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Country</th>
   </tr>
```

> Here I need to add rows dynamically....
>         is it possible?

```
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>Any Place</td>
        <td>Any Country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>place</td>
        <td>Any Country</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="but">mybutton</button>


$('#but').on('click', function(e){
    $('#mytable')
        .prepend('<tr><td>newcol1</td><td>newcol2</td><td>newcol3</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Does your posted jQuery not work? What goes wrong? Are there any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: No, the code is working. butt the problem is, row adding on the top of <th>, i need to add row in between <th></th> and <tr></tr>

Answer (score 3):

Use `tbody` to `prepend` new row. Otherwise, new row will be added before `th`.

```
$('#but').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#mytable tbody')
    //          ^^^^^
        .prepend('<tr><td>newcol1</td><td>newcol2</td><td>newcol3</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve,but if you are trying,to add a same row to top of table as well the end then try this,

```
$('#but').on('click', function(e){
    $('#mytable')
        .prepend('<tr><td>newcol1</td><td>newcol2</td><td>newcol3</td></tr>');
     $('#mytable')
        .append('<tr><td>newcol1</td><td>newcol2</td><td>newcol3</td></tr>');
});
```

Since you havent specified anything,i used the `<table>`,you should use `<tbody>` ideally.